# Show property which includes html tags

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I've an ember property which includes html tags (`<br />`, `<strong>`, `<p>`, `<span>`, and similar stuff).

How can i tell ember not to escape this text? Is there any default Handlebars helper from ember, or need I to write my own?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

From http://handlebarsjs.com/

> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a `{{expression}}`.
>       If you don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash".
>
> `{{{expression}}}`

Comment: Just in case if anyone is looking for Emblem equivalent, its `== expression`

Comment: As mentioned by morhook, you can also wrap the value in [Ember.String.htmlSafe()](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html#method_htmlSafe). This is useful if the value is being passed into an addon/component that you don't have full control of.

Answer (score 16):

Within `Ember.js` you can do this via the `htmlSafe` method, which is added to the `String` prototype, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/jNAQ6/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{App.html}} - {{App.unescaped}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({
    html: '<b>bold text</b>',
    unescaped: function(){
        return this.get('html').htmlSafe();
    }.property('html')
});​
```

Comment: This does not work. {{App.html}} will strip the html elements as well

Comment: `.htmlSafe()` is the method I needed

Comment: For latest Ember (2.6.1), I've used [Ember.String.htmlSafe() method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html#method_htmlSafe)

Answer (score 3):

**Ember 2.x, using JavaScript**

To make a string unescaped and output using Ember templates you can use `htmlSafe` helper.

```
Ember.String.htmlSafe('<div>someString</div>')
```

The returned string will not be HTML escaped by Handlebars template engine.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html#method_htmlSafe

**Use Handlebars Only**

Alternatively, you can pass the raw HTML to Handlebars template and get the raw HTML output by using triple brackets

*Inside Handlebars Template*

```
<div>{{{raw_html_content}}}</div>
```