# Ember.js view parameter displays html as plain text

Tags: view, parameters, ember.js

I have this view:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="articlesOne">
<div class="main">
    <div id="articlesOne">
        <h2 id="article-title">{{App.ArticlesOneController.article.title}}</h2>
        <h3 id="article-lead">{{App.ArticlesOneController.article.lead}}</h3>
        <div id="article-body">{{App.ArticlesOneController.article.body}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
</script>
```

When I change the `App.ArticlesOneController.article.title` property to, say `<p>Pragraph</p>`, the browser displays the plain text, ***not*** parsed as HTML.

I would like to display that in HTML, due to building an editor on that div. How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try triple brackets with `{{{App.ArticlesOneController.article.title}}}`. I think this link is useful for you: [Show property which includes html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450602/show-property-which-includes-html-tags)

Comment: Thx, that worked perfectly. I suppose I should start reading about Handlebars.