# Render html from a model property

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

One of my models has an `html` property which I want to render as-is:

```
{{html}}
```

But doing this, it will insert the html as text: no DOM elements are created. How can I insert some html from a property into the DOM, using the handlebars notation?

Comment: I'll leave this for reference: similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11451100/647991) question. Just add `htmlSafe()`.

Comment: Read The Fine Manual.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use the [htmlSafe](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html#method_htmlSafe) method, as jeckyll2hide pointed out, or you can use the [triple-stash](http://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping).

```
{{{html}}}
```